# How to force calling the coerceValue of a bindable property when another bindable property change?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I have a custom control like this:

```
<controls:CustomControl Value=".8" MaxValue=".7"/>
```

this is `Value` bindable property:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value), typeof(double), typeof(CustomControl), 2d,
                coerceValue: (bindable, value) =>
                 ((double)value).Clamp(0.05d, ((CustomControl)bindable).MaxValue));
```

The problem is that it only get evaluated when the `Value` changes, this won't work:

```
<controls:CustomControl Value=".8" MaxValue=".7"/>
```

But this will:

```
<controls:CustomControl MaxValue=".7" Value=".8"/>
```

isn't there a way to execute the `coerceValue` when another property changes (i.e., in its `propertyChanged`)?

Comment: There's an open issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5680

Comment: No, I didn't solve it

Comment: You can share the sample so that I can test it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it only get evaluated when the Value changes, this won't work:

It is an expect result. The method `Clamp` will returns value clamped to the inclusive range of min and max.

```
template<class T>
T Clamp(T x, T min, T max)
{
    if (x > max)
        return max;
    if (x < min)
        return min;
    return x;
}
```

When you set `Value` as 0.7 ,and `MaxValue` as 0.8, because 0.7 is large than 0.05 and less then 0.8 ,so it will return itself (0.7). And the method propertyChanged will never been called .

When you set `Value` as 0.8 ,and `MaxValue` as 0.7, it will return 0.8. And the method propertyChanged will been called .

Comment: Sorry, what do you suggest to solve the problem? I just needed something like `MyBindableProperty.CoerceValue`

Comment: You can set the default value when define the bindable property (such as 0) .And handle the logic in `PropertyChanged` .